# How to run a batch file of an application that takes images as arguments in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a batch file `run.bat` that requires many arguments for it to run. It is a part of an application named `GeoMatch` for which I have `GeoMatch.exe` present in the same folder as the .bat file.

In order to run the application, I need to run the batch file.

By using command prompt in Windows , I run the batch file as follows:

```
 C:\programs\test\GeoMatch_demo>GeoMatch -t template.jpg -1 10 -h 100 -s search1.
 jpg -m 0.7 -g 0.9
```

I get my desired output. However, when I try to run the same from my `Java Application` I am not getting the desired result.

My Java code:

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.lang.*;

  public class BatchDemo
    { 
       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
      { 
        try{
         String cmd;

           try { 

         String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\programs\\test\\GeoMatch_demo\\run.bat","C:\\programs\test\\GeoMatch_demo\\Search1.jpg","C:\\programs\\test\\GeoMatch_demo\\template.jpg"};
           Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
           Process p = r.exec(command);
           p.waitFor();

            } catch (Exception e) 
            {

            System.out.println("Execution error");} 
        }
      catch(Exception e)
       {
     e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Also to run this .bat file we require 3 DLL's to be present in the same folder as the .bat file. I have added those 3 DLL's in my Java Project but still I don't get the desired result.

can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any error message? You're dlls should be present in the folder with the bat file and not in java project (you're just running external program)

Comment: @elrado: when I run my code, a command prompt opens but it shows this message "'GeoMatch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." ..but no errors as such are displayed

Comment: Can you add the bat file source?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: this is the bat file source : http://pastie.org/3570379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you execute the bat file from the java code you do not change the current directory in the `cmd`, meaning that you are not actually in `C:\\programs\\test\\GeoMatch_demo\\`. So the exe file can not be found. If you refer to the exe file with absolute path in the batch file, the problem should go away.

Comment: how do I change the current directory to point to  "C:\\programs\\test\\GeoMatch_demo\\" ? Also, do I need to pass those images along with their arguments as parameters to the batch file in my java code?

Comment: when i run my above code, I get the command prompt with the path C:\users\parth\workspace\BatchDemo>  ..is that what u mean by current directory?

Comment: Yes you will either need to pass in the image paths, or, alternatively, you can pass in just one variable that will be the relative path. Then you use this variable to find your exe file and to reference the images correctly. You can even `cd` in your script to the relative path so that you can avoid all the path concatenations.

Comment: About your second question: yes your current directory will be the one of your java project. You know that when you type in `GeoMatch` in command prompt it will work only if you were in the directory `C:\programs\test\GeoMatch_demo`. Same happens here.

Comment: ohh thanks I think I got it ! But then is there any any way I could change that current directory to point to C:\programs\test\GeoMatch_demo> and not C:\users\parth\workspace\BatchDemo> using my java code

Comment: You don't need to do in the java code directly (also I think there is no such way). Just add to your batch file a cd command as first step: you will change the current directory there.

Comment: and cd should be followed by the absolute path where the .bat is right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8753/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-parth-doshi)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it worked fine ! :)  I would love to chat some other day though, have loads of things to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the path C:\programs\test\GeoMatch_demo into PATH environment variable.